# Proof in Orthogonal Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm studying with "Linear Algebra with application 8th edition" and in Ch. 5.2, 215p, I cannot understand the author's proof.

> If $ Y$ is a subspace of $R^n$, then $Y^⊥$  is also a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> $ pf) $
> If $\textrm{x} \in Y^⊥$ and $\alpha$ is a scalar, then , for any $ \textrm{y} \in Y $ ,
> $$ (\alpha \textrm{x})^T \textrm{y} = \alpha(\textrm{x}^T \textrm{y}) = \alpha \cdot 0 = 0 $$
> Therefore, $\alpha \textrm{x} \in Y^⊥.$ If $\textrm{x}_1 $ and $\textrm{x}_2$ are elements of $Y^⊥$, then
> $$(\textrm{x}_1 + \textrm{x}_2) ^T \textrm{y} = \textrm{x} _1 ^T\textrm{y} + \textrm{x}_2^T\textrm{y}=0+0=0  $$
> for each $\textrm{y} \in Y $. Hence $ \textrm{x}_1 + \textrm{x}_2 \in \textrm{Y}^⊥$. Therefore, $\textrm{Y}^⊥$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

I think this means only that Y<sup>⊥</sup> is the closed set but nothing. Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: They are applying a theorem often called the subspace test.  If a nonempty subset of a vector space meets those two conditions, then you can prove that it is a subspace.  (It will then inherit the remaining axioms.)

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $Y^\perp$ is a subspace.

One just have to verify that $0 \in Y^\perp ,$ it is closed under scalar multiplication (in your proof, $\alpha x \in Y^\perp$) and it is closed under addition (in your proof, $x_1+x_2 \in Y^\perp$)

Reference: [Linear Subspace wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace)